# How do I put all these codes together to function as a single module?

Tags: excel, vba

This question might look silly but I have never tried this before.

How do you put these different codes to work as a single module?
I added a button in my worksheet hoping that it would process all the different requests once.

***Worsksheet name: WC***

**First**: ReplaceVlookupValues() is made to replace the vlookups by values so the macro can pick it up.

**Second**: Sub DeleteStatus() is made to delete the selected words in column ***H***.

**Third**: DeleteEmployeeCriteria() is made to delete the selected words in column ***CE***.

**Fourth**: DeleteOkIssueCriteria() is made to delete the selected words in column ***CP***.

```
Sub ReplaceVlookupValues()
'Copy A Range of Data
  Worksheets("WC").Range("A3:CP35000").Copy

'PasteSpecial Values Only
  Worksheets("WC").Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Clear Clipboard (removes "marching ants" around the original data set)
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  
End Sub


Sub DeleteStatus()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim toDelete As Variant

    ' set the words to delete
    toDelete = Array("Closed", "Resigned", "TBC")

    Dim colD As Range
    Set col = Sheet1.Range("H3:H" & Sheet1.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    With col
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=toDelete, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub


Sub DeleteEmployeeCriteria()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim toDelete As Variant

    ' set the words to delete
    toDelete = Array("0NotEmployee", "1NotEmployee")

    Dim colD As Range
    Set col = Sheet1.Range("CE3:CE" & Sheet1.Range("CE" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    With col
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=toDelete, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub


Sub DeleteOkIssueCriteria()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim toDelete As Variant

    ' set the words to delete
    toDelete = Array("OK")

    Dim colD As Range
    Set col = Sheet1.Range("CP3:CP" & Sheet1.Range("CP" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    With col
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=toDelete, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: There're several ways to do this, though a simple way is to make a new subroutine and call each other subroutine in the order you want.  Then all of the `screenupdating`, `enableevents`, etc., can be turned on/off in one subroutine.

Answer (score 2):

Example of my comments:

```
Sub Execute_Routines()
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculate = xlManual
        '--- 
        ReplaceVlookupValues
        DeleteEmployeeCriteria
        DeleteOkIssueCriteria
        '---
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculate = xlAutomatic
    End with
End Sub
```

The above works if you're in a single module.  If you work in other modules, you will need references and may need to actually use `Call`.

Comment: Should I add my code for each function somewhere in your code?

Comment: @LioDjo the code I have listed is simply added to the top or bottom of the module including your other code.  it will call them in the listed order (so if you want to change that order, VBA always goes line by line).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to call in the marching ants. Simply assign the range its own value.

`SpecialCells` is not needed to delete empty rows (see example in my code).  Make sure and add an Error Handler when using `SpecialCells`.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim CalculationMode As XlCalculation
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    CalculationMode = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    ReplaceVlookupValues
    DeleteSheet1Criteria DeleteStatusCriteria, "H"
    DeleteSheet1Criteria DeleteEmployeeCriteria, "CE"
    DeleteSheet1Criteria DeleteOkIssueCriteria, "CP"
    
    Application.Calculation = CalculationMode
End Sub


Sub ReplaceVlookupValues()
    With Worksheets("WC").Range("A3:CP35000")
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub

Sub DeleteSheet1Criteria(Criteria As Variant, Column As Variant)
    Dim Target As Range
    With Sheet1.Columns(Column)
        Set Target = .Cells(3, 1)
        Set Target = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
        Set Target = Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    With Target
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Criteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    
    Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub

Function DeleteStatusCriteria()
    DeleteStatusCriteria = Array("Closed", "Resigned", "TBC")
End Function

Function DeleteEmployeeCriteria()
    DeleteEmployeeCriteria = Array("0NotEmployee", "1NotEmployee")
End Function

Function DeleteOkIssueCriteria()
    DeleteOkIssueCriteria = Array("OK")
End Function
```